# Tabulator are not working on Midone template

Tags: javascript, laravel, tabulator

I imported my `tabulator.js` from template using `webpack.min.js` I added `.js("resources/js/tabulator.js", "dist/js")` to my `webpack.min.js`, and run `npm run dev`

then I imported my `<script src="{{ asset('dist/js/tabulator.js') }}"></script>` bellow `<script src="{{ asset('dist/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

but as soon I imported it, i got errors `<script src="{{ asset('dist/js/tabulator.js') }}"></script>` from both `app.js` and `tabulator.js` but i kept going since it was working just fine

but then i notice my filters are not working, when i try to type on console `table.setFilter()` or `table.download()` it isn't working. below is my js

```
if ($("#role-tabulator").length) {
    // Setup Tabulator
    let table = new Tabulator("#role-tabulator", {
        ajaxURL: "/role",
        ajaxFiltering: true,
        ajaxSorting: true,
        printAsHtml: true,
        printStyled: true,
        pagination: "remote",
        paginationSize: 10,
        paginationSizeSelector: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        layout: "fitColumns",
        responsiveLayout: "collapse",
        placeholder: "No matching records found",
        columns: [
            {
                formatter: "responsiveCollapse",
                width: 40,
                minWidth: 30,
                hozAlign: "center",
                resizable: false,
                headerSort: false,
            },

            // For HTML table
            {
                title: "NAME",
                minWidth: 200,
                responsive: 0,
                field: "name",
                vertAlign: "middle",
                print: false,
                download: false,
                formatter(cell, formatterParams) {
                    return `<div>
                        <div class="font-medium whitespace-nowrap">${
                            cell.getData().name
                        }</div>
                    </div>`;
                },
            },{
                title: "ACTIONS",
                minWidth: 200,
                field: "actions",
                responsive: 1,
                hozAlign: "center",
                vertAlign: "middle",
                print: false,
                download: false,
                formatter(cell, formatterParams) {
                    let a =
                        $(`<div class="flex lg:justify-center items-center">
                        <a class="edit flex items-center mr-3" href="javascript:;">
                            <i data-lucide="check-square" class="w-4 h-4 mr-1"></i> Edit
                        </a>
                        <a class="delete flex items-center text-danger" href="javascript:;">
                            <i data-lucide="trash-2" class="w-4 h-4 mr-1"></i> Delete
                        </a>
                    </div>`);
                    $(a)
                        .find(".edit")
                        .on("click", function () {
                            alert("EDIT");
                        });

                    $(a)
                        .find(".delete")
                        .on("click", function () {
                            alert("DELETE");
                        });

                    return a[0];
                },
            },

            // For print format
            {
                title: "NAME",
                field: "name",
                visible: false,
                print: true,
                download: true,
            },
        ],
        renderComplete() {
            createIcons({
                icons,
                "stroke-width": 1.5,
                nameAttr: "data-lucide",
            });
        },
    });

    // Redraw table onresize
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        table.redraw();
        createIcons({
            icons,
            "stroke-width": 1.5,
            nameAttr: "data-lucide",
        });
    });

    // Filter function
    function filterHTMLForm() {
        let field = $("#role-tabulator-html-filter-field").val();
        let type = $("#role-tabulator-html-filter-type").val();
        let value = $("#role-tabulator-html-filter-value").val();
        table.setFilter(field, type, value);
    }

    // On submit filter form
    $("#role-tabulator-html-filter-form")[0].addEventListener(
        "keypress",
        function (event) {
            let keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
            if (keycode == "13") {
                event.preventDefault();
                filterHTMLForm();
            }
        }
    );

    // On click go button
    $("#role-tabulator-html-filter-go").on("click", function (event) {
        filterHTMLForm();
    });

    // On reset filter form
    $("#role-tabulator-html-filter-reset").on("click", function (event) {
        $("#role-tabulator-html-filter-field").val("name");
        $("#role-tabulator-html-filter-type").val("like");
        $("#role-tabulator-html-filter-value").val("");
        filterHTMLForm();
    });

    // Export
    $("#role-tabulator-export-csv").on("click", function (event) {
        table.download("csv", "data.csv");
    });

    $("#role-tabulator-export-json").on("click", function (event) {
        table.download("json", "data.json");
    });

    $("#role-tabulator-export-xlsx").on("click", function (event) {
        window.XLSX = xlsx;
        table.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx", {
            sheetName: "Products",
        });
    });

    $("#role-tabulator-export-html").on("click", function (event) {
        table.download("html", "data.html", {
            style: true,
        });
    });

    // Print
    $("#role-tabulator-print").on("click", function (event) {
        table.print();
    });
}
```

Comment: there is no need to trigger a redraw on your table on resize, tabulator should do that for you

Comment: what do you see if you console log the values being passed into the `setFilter` function?